Module Snakemake from Gitlab can't verify certificate
I try to import a module in my Snakefile from my gitlab.
Resources from here : https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#code-hosting-providers
My gitlab is self hosted on my server with this kind of adress (it is https) : https://gitlab.example.fr
I run my Snakemake from a different server but both on the same network.
The code in my Snakefile is :
module qc_rnaseq:
    snakefile:
        gitlab("ngs_workflows/qc_rnaseq", path="Snakefile", tag="master", host="gitlab.example.fr")
    config: config

I have the following error
Failed to open source file https://gitlab.example.fr/api/v4/projects/ngs_workflows%2Fqc_rnaseq/repository/files/Snakefile/raw?ref=master
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='gitlab.example.fr', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v4/projects/ngs_workflows%2Fqc_rnaseq/repository/files/Snakefile/raw?ref=master (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))

I tried to add a add a GITLAB_TOKEN in my environment but I understand the problem does not come from here since my repository is not even private.
I understand the problem comes from the verification of the certificate.
How can I avoid Snakemake to check the certificate ? Or force Snakemake to accept it ?
